# What is needed for Intel's fTPM technology to to work?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, chipset, tpm

I am planning to upgrade my PC and to buy some new parts and I want to make sure that I can skip the physical TPM header on the motherboard so I can compare more motherboards and options. I find it quite difficult to find any with TPM headers actually, not to say that no homepage I shop on give me the option to sort their stock for the TPM option.

As I understand it from different forums, Intel's website and Microsoft's homepage regarding TPM, so is the following needed to get Windows Hello to work (which uses a TPM):

- a chipset with Intel® Platform Trust Technology (Intel® PTT)
- a processor which supports Intel® Trusted Execution Technology (Intel® TXT)

Is that all or can the motherboard manufacturer also have some input on this so I could end up with a motherboard without any support for theses features regardless of those technologies being incoperated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no variations across devices as the TPM and TXT protocols are end-to-end Intel implementations using Intel provided drivers via Windows update.

There are differences in TPM versioning however. Check to see if you have a TPM 2.0 device or such. With Microsoft making it mandatory for new Windows 10 devices in 2016 to have TPM 2.0 support, there may be requirements in Windows Hello to support the same.

Modern fTPM is different from standard 'TPM' in that it is a chipless implementation and less secure. It will tick all but the most stringent of hardware's TPM support needs and will allow Hello to work. All fTPM implementations are 'the latest' so versioning doesn't matter. fTPM should work on any CPU that supports Intel SGX Instructions as well as any Ryzen or later motherboards.

Comment: Alright so I don't have to be sure about, for example, Asus having these technologies inside of their motherboards because as long as the chipset that is used in the motherboard is supporting it so is everything else also going to do so. Did I understand that right from your first  part of the answer?

Yes everything I'm purchasing from now on are going to be products supporting TPM 2.0 because of the reason that you stated.

Comment: No. TPM is not a chipset technology, it's an independent chip on the board and you do need a board that says it has it. You can get many boards without headers but with TPM (and they are identical) is what I am saying. 

When I say end-to-end I refer to the fact that because it is an Intel technology, like Thunderbolt for example, you will not run into variations in support based on motherboard maker. If the board says it has TPM, it will work for everything that needs TPM, as long as it's not an older version than needed.

Comment: However, to add to that for correctness, fTPM, which you referenced in the title is different to TPM so I am updating my answer for that now.

Comment: Why do you say fTPM is less secure? Discrete TPM chips are vulnerable to bus sniffing attacks while these are not possible with fTPM.